# Unable to restric IAM Role to a specific key and subkeys in S3 (getting AccessDenied)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I have 2 IAM Roles A & B that are assumed by 2 EC2 instances. I would like to grand role A access to `ServerA/` key and all subkeys and objects in a S3 bucket.

I would like to to the same for Role B but give it access to only `ServerB/` key and all subkeys and objects starting with that key

S3 bucket layout:

```
- SqlServerBackups/
    - ServerA/
    - DBAdmin/
        - DIFF/
        - backup1.bak
        - ..
        - FULL/
        - fullbackup1.bak
        - ..
    - ServerB/
    - DBAdmin/
        - DIFF/
        - backup1.bak
        - ..
        - FULL/
        - fullbackup1.bak
        - ..
```

When I try to perform this `sync`

`aws s3 sync E:\BACKUPS\VOL01\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\ s3://bucketname/SqlServerBackups/ServerA/`

operation from `ServerA` I am getting this error:

```
upload failed: E:\BACKUPS\VOL01\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\OperatorData\LOG\OperatorData.trn to
s3://bucketname/SqlServerBackups/ServerA/OperatorData/LOG/OperatorData_LOG_20221011_111601.trn 
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

This is the custom IAM policy attached to `ServerA` EC2 :

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/ServerA/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

What am I missing here? My policy seems to be causing the issue but I am not sure what permissions I am missing to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<<bucketname>>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "ServerB/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<<bucketname>>/ServerB/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me spot a mistake in my policy, I forgot that my `s3` bucket contained a root key called `SqlServerBackups` (I have updated my s3 bucket layout in my question. After pretending that key using your suggested policy, I was able to run the `sync` command fine. Thank you :)